# Python numpy array of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a problem on creating a numpy array of numpy arrays.
I would create it in a loop:

```
a=np.array([])
while(...):
   ...
   b= //a numpy array generated
   a=np.append(a,b)
   ...
```

Desired result:

```
[[1,5,3], [9,10,1], ..., [4,8,6]]
```

Real result:

```
[1,5,3,9,10,1,... 4,8,6]
```

Is it possible? I don't know the final dimension of the array, so I can't initialize it with a fixed dimension.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Never append to `numpy` arrays in a loop: it is the one operation that NumPy is very bad at compared with basic Python. This is because you are making a full copy of the data each `append`, which will cost you quadratic time.

Instead, just append your arrays to a Python list and convert it at the end; the result is simpler and faster:

```
a = []

while ...:
    b = ... # NumPy array
    a.append(b)
a = np.asarray(a)
```

As for why your code doesn't work: `np.append` doesn't behave like `list.append` at all. In particular, it won't create new dimensions when appending. You would have to create the initial array with two dimensions, then append with an explicit axis argument.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The big problem is that I need about 100 arrays each one with a very big dimension, each one has got 1440000 integers inside. With list my program is killed by OS.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you guess how many elements you will have, and preallocate a big enough array? If not you might have to get very clever, like building the output array in chunks or something.

Comment: You should also be able to preallocate using a larger array, then use a view of that array at the end once you know how many elements are actually present.

Comment: Finally I followed your suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

we can try it also :

```
arr1 = np.arange(4)
arr2 = np.arange(5,7)
arr3 = np.arange(7,12)

array_of_arrays = np.array([arr1, arr2, arr3])
array_of_arrays
np.concatenate(array_of_arrays)
```

Comment: Yes the point is that each inside array should be numpy not list as this saves all the space. Then make an array from the list of arrays.

Comment: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or 
shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.