# Making array of arrays

Tags: python

Basically, im trying to make array of arrays in python and i don't know how really. It needs to be in "for" loop and each time it goes trough loop, it needs to add array of some numbers to the array of arrays but of course on index+1

EDIT:
this is what i already tried, but it gives me error:

```
for x in range(5):
        poljeRazina[x][x]=1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250129/python-numpy-array-of-numpy-arrays

Comment: @Bogy what's your expected output. Mention that clearly so I can understand what you actually want because your question is not conveying complete sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, arrays are called Lists. This could be helpful when googling.
Also, you can declare them like this (depth-based):

```
x = [[]]
```

Then...

```
for big in range(10):                          #outer loop
    for small in range(10):                    #inner loop
        x[big].append(small*big)               #add new number
        print('%03d' % x[big][small], end=" ") #we print the number padded to 3 digits
    x.append([])                               #add another internal list
    print()                                    #move down to next line
```

Equals...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension might help

```
[list(range(i)) for i in range(5)]
```