# Can we initialise a numpy array of numpy arrays with different shapes using some constructor?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, ragged

I want an array that looks like this,

```py
array([array([[1, 1], [2, 2]]), array([3, 3])], dtype=object)
```

I can make an empty array and then assign elements one by one like this,

```py
z = [np.array([[1,1],[2,2]]), np.array([3,3])]
x = np.empty(shape=2, dtype=object)
x[0], x[1] = z
```

I thought if this possible then so should be this: `x = np.array(z, dtype=object)`, but that gets me the error: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)`.

So is the way given above the only way to make a ragged numpy array? Or, is there a nice one line constructor/function we can can call to make the array `x` from above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python numpy array of numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250129/python-numpy-array-of-numpy-arrays)

Comment: No, I am not looking to append or concatenate a row/column. I want an array of other array objects which happen to be different shapes as shown in the example array `x`.